# Is it possible to migrate resources from subscription A to subscription B in Azure?

Tags: azure, migration, virtual-machine, database-migration

I need to migrate a resource from subscription A to subscription B. But, when I read the documentation, there might some of the resource can't be migrated.[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources)

So, what is the best practice for migrating from subscription A to subscription B. On my resource there are Virtual Machine and PostgreSQL database. Is it I just manually backup my file to local and redeploy it to a new subscription, and backup my database to local ?

These are my resources that need to migrate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources you have are `Microsoft.Storage` (Disks), `Microsoft.Network` (Network interfaces and private endpoint), `Microsoft.Compute` (Virtual Machine) and `Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL` (azure database for postgresql).

Except for Private endpoints you can move all other resources to another subscription.

[image: private endpoints cannot be moved(image)]

Reference :
[Steps to move resources to another subscription.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#use-the-portal)

Comment: But, if I migrate the resource, so it will removed from subscription A (Resource) ? or it will be cloning ?

Comment: @RudyTriSaputra, if the validations are passed and once you move then the resources will be placed in Subscription B and removed from Subscription A . it will not clone the resources. and also while performing a move operation  both the source and target resource groups will be locked so you can't manually perform any operation on those resource groups .

Comment: @RudyTriSaputra, if the answer was helpful would you like to upvote or accept the answer so it can be used as reference for community users?

Comment: One more question, is it possible when the processing is failed ? what if when it was failed ? my data will loss or not ?

Comment: you mean to say validations is failed or the move process is failed ?

Comment: Yes, I mean like that

Comment: if validations is failed then move will not happen .. 
but if the move operation is failed then your move will not have been occured .when the selected resources from subscription A are all completely and safely moved to the other subscription B then only the resources will actually show up in a resource group in Subscription B instead of A.. so it means operation will do copy from subscription A and paste in subscription B and when copy paste is successful then it will delete in subscription A. this is the whole process.